# Making a bridge for communication between python and smalltalk

Tags: python, sockets, smalltalk

I am making a project in pharo that will extend it and make it more visual for also further extending the 3d application Blender. Blender uses mainly python for extensions called "Addons" , to be precise python 3.2. So what I want is to make a bridge between pharo (smalltalk) and blender (python).

For now I have focused on sockets and XMLRPC but I was wondering if there are tools out there and choices to further help on my saga.

I dont have high demands, for now a simple access to class attributes and call of python methods should be enough, but if I can add additional power to my bridge later it will so much better. Ideally the bridge later one could be used for making pharo use libraries from other language like Java , C# etc

Comment: SmallTalk is one of my favourite languages, but It was long time ago when I have a  project using SmallTalk :) It was VisualAge SmallTalk :) think the best way is to communicate using sockets which will allow to have these 2 applications working on different computers which is a great advantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSockets sending JSON messages between Smalltalk and Python could be the bleeding edge yet long-term quite a promising way to go. Smalltalk has quite good WebSockets support, I suppose Python as well.

Comment: Why web sockets, when you can use regular sockets?  Regular sockets are easier, this isn't a web app...

Comment: WebSockets goes through firewalls on port 80 because they are upgraded from a regular HTTP connection. WebSockets also send/receive messages by framing them appropriately while plain sockets send/receive byte by byte.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org)
Its an awesome bridge between many languages.

Answer (score 1):

You may find some interesting information and ideas if you take a look how it has been solved for OpenQwaq [Python Integration](http://squeakingalong.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/openqwaq-python-integration/)

Answer (score 1):

I remember a ruby->dotNet bridge which was ported to some smalltalk as far as I remember.
(Ruby/.Net Bridge / 2004 Benjamin Schroeder and John R. Pierce). It covered passing of exceptions, callbacks etc. May make a good starting point for your work. Don't know where and how to get it, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make perfect sense to have a java api, instead of java. And I believe it's not that hard to do. And I'm sure plenty of people have done it. One of them being http://cgchan.com/suicidator/. If you download it, you'll see it has a "smallish" python bridge between python and the java implementation of suicidator, sitting in SCG.jar, and the other jars included in the package. I'm just looking for an open source implementation of this other than hacking the code and try to reverse engineer what they've done.